# How to debug a problem when loading native libs in Java?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I have a problem relative to JNI and Java. Here is the thing : the client wants us to install a certain app on his system. This app uses native libs, but the client does not want to put these libs in his system folder, for reasons I don't really know or understand, but can't change.

To circumvent thius problem, I tried to launch the JVM with `-Djava.library.path`, putting the right dlls in it. But the fact is, I have a [`UnsatisfiedLinkError`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError.html) when I try to launch my project. From what I can see, the problem is not in the main dll called (because the file obviously exists, I saw it when debugging), I think that must be some of the libs linked by this first dll that are problematic, but I don't know how to find what dll is missing.

Any idea on how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first port of call (even for JNI debugging) is always [Dependency Walker](http://dependencywalker.com/). If nothing else, it will tell you every other DLL that your DLL depends on.

[`ldd`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ldd) is the equivalent for Linux.

Comment: It looks really promising. I'll try tomorrow, if this works you're my savior.

Comment: @Adam Batkin : took the liberty of adding ldd to your reponse, for the sake of future readers, I hope you won't mind.

Answer (score 0):

I think that parameter is for specifying directories, not files. So if your dll is `c:\mylibs\lib1.dll` then you have to set its value to `c:\mylibs`.

I don't know if it allows multiple paths. Let me check.

**Edit**

That parameter do allow multiple paths.

See section 2.7 in http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/start.html

It doesn't specify the format but I imagine you can use the same separator than in classpath. It says you can also use the PATH system variable.

Comment: tried multiple paths, put the dirs. It's just that something is still missing.

Comment: Oh, ok. And the exception don't say "*ModuleName* missing"?

Comment: No, it said it has a problem with the class I know exists, but I don't know more details.